# How to prepare directories in private file system?

Tags: 7, files

I've configured private file system. Using it from UI works well.
I want to generate dump site content via devel_generate with custom modifications. So I'm hooking into Node API for assigning sample PDF files to nodes.

Inside private directory I want to create directory structure:

```
  $dir = sprintf('private://org%d/%d/person%d', $this->getOrganization()->nid,
                    date('Y'), $this->getEmployee()->uid);

  if (!file_prepare_directory($dir)) {
    throw new Exception('Cannot create document file directory or it\'s not writable');
  }
```

But exception is thrown.

How to set proper directory permissions? Content is generated  via drush command - drush genc.

Comment: You need to run Drush under the same user your web server runs, or give Drush write permissions over the private file system

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying things like: sudo -uwww-data /usr/bin/drush cc all
but getting drush command not found

Comment: I've same error when creating nodes via UI also...

Comment: Sorry, would need access to your server to be able to debug, can't do it from here

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved it by passing proper flag (for UI):

```
file_prepare_directory($dir, FILE_CREATE_DIRECTORY);
```

For using drush command still don't know and failing.